# Constant values not reflected at run time

Tags: java, compiler-construction, constants

Suppose that you compile the following two classes. The first is meant to represent a client; the second, a library class.

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Lib.FIRST + " " +
                           Lib.SECOND + " " +
                           Lib.THIRD);
    }
}


public class Lib{
    private Lib() { }; // Uninstantiable
    public static final String FIRST = "the";
    public static final String SECOND = null;
    public static final String THIRD = "set";
}
```

prints:

> {the null set}

Now suppose that you modify the library class as follows and recompile it but not the client program:

```
public class Lib{
    private Lib() { }; // Uninstantiable
    public static final String FIRST = "physics";
    public static final String SECOND = "chemistry";
    public static final String THIRD = "biology";
}
```

prints:

> {the chemistry set}

Why is the `SECOND` value changed but not the `FIRST` or `THIRD`?

Comment: Are there two "Lib" classes in the classpath?  Did you restart the VM?  What's your container?

Comment: This is straight out of [Java Puzzlers](http://www.amazon.com/Java-Puzzlers-Traps-Pitfalls-Corner/dp/032133678X). Same string constants and everything. It's a great read if you want to understand the edgier cases of Java.

Comment: This question is indeed plagiarized word for word from Java Puzzlers (puzzle #93).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a known caveat - constants are inlined when you compile your client program, so you have to recompile it as well.

**See also:**

- [Is Java guaranteed to inline string constants if they can be determined at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406616/is-java-guaranteed-to-inline-string-constants-if-they-can-be-determined-at-compi)
- [Are all compile-time constants inlined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377819/are-all-compile-time-constants-inlined)

Comment: (+1) Curious... didn't know that.

Comment: This is the accepted answer, but the response is not quite subtle enough.  Specifically, null is not a constant expression, so it is not inlined, while the other two values are defined with a constant expression, so their values are inlined (which is why "the chemistry set" is what ends up being printed).

Answer (score 3):

The values (i.e. "the" and "set") are inlined while `null` is not inlined by the compiler while compilation. To avoid something like that you can use a accessor method.

Comment: Aren't accessor methods discouraged on using on static fields? Is this an exceptional case?

Comment: I was just saying if he wanted to avoid recompiling the client class itself.

Comment: No, I completely understand your intention, I am not saying you said something wrong, don't get me wrong. Just trying to see if you are aware of anything like there is an exception to use accessor in this.