# Is it safe to replace single class file in a jar file?

Tags: java, jar, patch, executable-jar

Is it safe to replace a single class file in a jar file?

Do the class files reference each other in such a way that this is not safe?

Grae

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can run `jar uf mJarFile.jar com\example\mClass.class`.

However, be aware that if the class defined constant `static final` primitive or String variables, then those values will have been [in-lined into other classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406616/is-java-guaranteed-to-inline-string-constants-if-they-can-be-determined-at-compi?answertab=votes#tab-top) (and so the values contained in your newer class won't be used).

Answer (score 4):

jar command (provided in Sun JDK bin) to replace class.

However, you need to understand following.

```
jar uf myJar com\test\MyClass.class
```

Here your class resides in com.test package

If you class has any sub classes, then generally those classes are also created as
     MyClass$MySubclass.class

Apart from MyClass.class you all need to replace/add those sub classes.class.
such as

```
jar uf myJar com\test\MyClass$MySubclass.class
```

It is also important to understand if your changes involved in any method prototype change,
you must re-compile those dependent classes and use it.

Above all, if your jar is signed, you must resign your jar. Because signature will be lost if you change anything in jar.