# Order of excecution, static blocks

Tags: java

I have following scenario
    package com.example.test;

```
public class StaticTest {

    public static final String STATIC_VAR="Static Var";

    static{
        System.out.println("Static Block Called....");
    }
public static void init(){}
}

package com.example.test;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test static initialization");
        String staticvar =StaticTest.STATIC_VAR;
        System.out.println("Referred static variable--> "+ staticvar);
        System.out.println("Calling static method");
        StaticTest.init();
        System.out.println("Static method invoked");
    }

}
```

The output I am getting is

```
Test static initialization
Referred static variable--> Static Var
Calling static method
**Static Block Called....**
Static method invoked
```

And output I was expecting was

```
Test static initialization
**Static Block Called....**
Referred static variable--> Static Var
Calling static method
Static method invoked
```

I was thinking that as soon as I refer static variable static block will get executed.

any explanation?

Comment: Please see [Java static class initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499214/java-static-class-initialization) and [What order are static blocks and static variables in a class executed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448465/in-what-order-are-static-blocks-and-static-variables-in-a-class-executed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary reason is that you declared `STATIC_VAR` as constant value, which will be inlined by the compiler instead of being referenced. Change the code to

```
public static /*final*/ String STATIC_VAR="Static Var";
```

and you will get the behaviour you expect.

See [§12.4.1. When Initialization Occurs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#d5e14527%3a) of the Java Language Specification:

> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - ...
> - A static field declared by T is used and the field is **not a constant** variable (§4.12.4).

See the other answers on `inlining` of constant values for the technical background.

Answer (score 3):

```
String staticvar =StaticTest.STATIC_VAR;
```

does not load the class `StaticTest`. Instead, the compiler *inlines* the *value* of the constant into `MainClass`. So at runtime, this code will be executed:

```
String staticvar = "Static Var";
```

The JLS calls this a "[constant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)":

> A variable of primitive type or type String, that is final  and
>   initialized with a compile-time constant expression (§15.28), is
>   called a constant variable.

which means that `StaticTest.init();` is the first time when the VM has to actually load the class. This causes the execution of the static block.

Answer (score 3):

Because the variable is `public static final` it is being inlined by the compiler.

All references to it are being replaced by the actual value as it cannot change, this is known as a Compile Time Constant.

Your code is essentially being compiled to:

```
System.out.println("Test static initialization");
String staticvar = "Static Var";
```

If you assign the value to the return value of a method -

```
public static final String STATIC_VAR=getStaticVar();
private static String getStaticVar() {
    return "Static Var";
}
```

You will get the result you expect.

There is a [good SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1406634/2071828) the explains inlining and the guarantees given by the JLS on compile time constants.