# How can I set breakpoint on accessing public static final vars?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, static, constants

When I try to set variable access breakpoint in Eclipse Kepler (I didn't check other versions) on public static final constants Eclipse is creating normal breakpoint as shown below.
[image: Normal breakpoint on variable]

Is it possible to debug access to public static final variables in Java on Eclipse Kepler?

Comment: And the normal breakpoint doesn't block access?

Comment: It doesn't. Whats more - variable breakpoint should look different and it should have a little tick sign on the bottom.

Comment: Why do you need this kind of feature - debugging `String` creation doesn't seem to be that valuable?

Comment: I'm not debugging creation of this string. Breakpoint on variable usually allows to debug access to this var.

Comment: @home - breakpoint on variable is called watchpoint. You can read about this here: http://www.eclipse-tips.com/tips/29-types-of-breakpoints-in-eclipse#Watchpoint

Comment: @grizwold: I know about watchpoints. Your String probably gets inlined, so that you cannot hit the breakpoint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406616/is-java-guaranteed-to-inline-string-constants-if-they-can-be-determined-at-compi

Answer (score 0):

There is a quite old [known bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=216098) on eclipse about the impossibility to add watchpoints on final field, that should be fixed on the next release of eclipse (4.4).
However, as home said  in his comment, your string beeing a compile-time constant expression (see JLS7 4.12.4) it is likely to be inlined, and so even when this bug will get fixed, you wont be able to add a watch point on your field.