# Why my class is not getting loaded

Tags: java, class, classloader

I am confused with the output of the below code. I know first static block gets executed after class loading but why is my class Test6 not getting loaded. Can someone please clarify.

```
package com.vikash.General;

public class Test5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Test6.FOO);
    }
    static {
        System.out.println("Initializing B");
    }
}
class Test6{

    public static final String FOO = "foo";
    static {
        System.out.println("Initializing A");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting o/p Initializing B
foo

Answer (score 9):

`Test6.FOO` refers to `Test6`, but the field is a `public static final String` initialized from a compile-time constant, so it [will be inlined by the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406616/is-java-guaranteed-to-inline-string-constants-if-they-can-be-determined-at-compi), and `Test6` does not need to be loaded at all.

Comment: Indeed. When removing the `final` the static initalizer will be invoked

Comment: @Thilo Can you explain "it will be inlined by the compiler". I cannot understand. This is new to me

Comment: In effect, the code becomes `System.out.println("foo")`. The compiler replaces the reference to the field with the String literal. At runtime, `Test6` is not needed for this line of code.

Comment: This can lead to problems if you later change `Test6.FOO` to another string. `Test5` will still print the old version (unless you also recompile `Test5`).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be because the compiler is inlining the reference to the string literal `"foo"`, so the JRE doesn't actually bother loading `Test6` to get it.

If you make a change such as:

```
public static final String FOO = new String("foo");
```

then the class `Test6` does get loaded (and its `static` block gets executed).

Comment: It also works with a literal when `FOO` is not final. But in case it should be, your solution works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class loader you will get the desired output

```
Class.forName("<package>.Test6");
```

Comment: Why not just `Class<?> foo = Test6.class` ?

Comment: anything would work. I just gave it as OP was confused about class loading issue.

Comment: Not really. An expression like `System.out.println(Test6.FOO)` would normally also load the class (but not in this case).

Answer (score -3):

Test6 is not initialized at all.

the foo is static, which means it can be used before class is intitialized and after a class is load.

Comment: I don´t know if i understand this answer completly, but i am pretty sure it´s wrong and doesn´t answer the question.

Comment: because it doesn´t explain why `Test6` is not loaded. It is just follwed by a confusing explenation of `foo is static`, which at this point is unrelated to the behavior. Actually this is the question, despite `foo` beeing `static`, why doesn´t it load `Test6` and hence call the `static initializer block`

Comment: I told you it's loaded into JVM but not initialized.

Comment: So you are telling foo can be used before class is initialized and after a class load but not in between? I am really confused what you want to tell us and which class do you refer to.